# variable sharing in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard, tflearn

I am trying to implement a siamese network for the first time. I don't have any experience with variable sharing. I don't know why I become this Error "Variable conv2/W does not exist, or was not created with tf.get_variable(). Did you mean to set reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE in VarScope?"                        Any help is appreciated

```
from __future__ import division, print_function, absolute_import

import tensorflow as tf

import tflearn
from tflearn.layers.core import input_data, dropout, fully_connected
from tflearn.layers.conv import conv_2d, max_pool_2d
from tflearn.layers.normalization import local_response_normalization
from tflearn.layers.estimator import regression

# Data loading and preprocessing
import tflearn.datasets.mnist as mnist
X, Y, testX, testY = mnist.load_data(one_hot=True)
X = X.reshape([-1, 28, 28, 1])
testX = testX.reshape([-1, 28, 28, 1])


def tower_network(reuse = True):
    network = tflearn.input_data(shape=(None,28,28,1))
    network = tflearn.conv_2d(network, 32,1, activation='relu',reuse=reuse, scope='conv1')
    network = tflearn.conv_2d(network, 64,1, activation='relu',reuse=reuse, scope='conv2') 
    network = tflearn.conv_2d(network, 128,1, activation='relu',reuse=reuse, scope='conv3')

    network = tflearn.max_pool_2d(network, 2, strides=2)

    network = tflearn.fully_connected(network, 512, activation='relu',reuse=reuse, scope='fc1')

    network = tflearn.dropout(network, 0.5)
    return network


def similarity_network( net1, net2):
    num_classes = 2
    network = tflearn.merge([net1,net2], mode='concat', axis=1, name='Merge') # merge net1 and net2 networks
    # fully connected layers
    network = tflearn.fully_connected(network, 2048, activation='relu')
    network = tflearn.dropout(network, 0.5)
    network = tflearn.fully_connected(network, 2048, activation='relu')
    network = tflearn.dropout(network, 0.5) 
    # softmax layers
    network = tflearn.fully_connected(network, num_classes, activation='softmax')
    return network




net1 = tower_network()
net2 = tower_network(reuse=True)

#similarity network
network = similarity_network( net1, net2)
#output layer
#network = tflearn.regression(network, optimizer='sgd', loss='hinge_loss', learning_rate=0.02)
network = tflearn.regression(network, optimizer='sgd', loss='categorical_crossentropy', learning_rate=0.02)

# Training
model = tflearn.DNN(network, tensorboard_verbose=0)
model.fit({'input': X}, {'target': Y}, n_epoch=20,
           validation_set=({'input': testX}, {'target': testY}),
snapshot_step=100, show_metric=True, run_id='convnet_mnist')
```

Answer (score 0):

In `net1 = tower_network()`, the parameter `reuse` is set to its default value, which is `True`. 
This leads in tensorflow trying to reuse a variable with the same name, which does not exist yet.

Replacing the line with `net1 = tower_network(reuse=False)` should solve the issue.

```
from __future__ import division, print_function, absolute_import

import tensorflow as tf

import tflearn
from tflearn.layers.core import input_data, dropout, fully_connected
from tflearn.layers.conv import conv_2d, max_pool_2d
from tflearn.layers.normalization import local_response_normalization
from tflearn.layers.estimator import regression

# Data loading and preprocessing
import tflearn.datasets.mnist as mnist
X, Y, testX, testY = mnist.load_data(one_hot=True)
X = X.reshape([-1, 28, 28, 1])
testX = testX.reshape([-1, 28, 28, 1])


def tower_network(reuse = True):
    network = tflearn.input_data(shape=(None,28,28,1))
    network = tflearn.conv_2d(network, 32,1, activation='relu',reuse=reuse, scope='conv1')
    network = tflearn.conv_2d(network, 64,1, activation='relu',reuse=reuse, scope='conv2') 
    network = tflearn.conv_2d(network, 128,1, activation='relu',reuse=reuse, scope='conv3')

    network = tflearn.max_pool_2d(network, 2, strides=2)

    network = tflearn.fully_connected(network, 512, activation='relu',reuse=reuse, scope='fc1')

    network = tflearn.dropout(network, 0.5)
    return network


def similarity_network( net1, net2):
    num_classes = 2
    network = tflearn.merge([net1,net2], mode='concat', axis=1, name='Merge') # merge net1 and net2 networks
    # fully connected layers
    network = tflearn.fully_connected(network, 2048, activation='relu')
    network = tflearn.dropout(network, 0.5)
    network = tflearn.fully_connected(network, 2048, activation='relu')
    network = tflearn.dropout(network, 0.5) 
    # softmax layers
    network = tflearn.fully_connected(network, num_classes, activation='softmax')
    return network




net1 = tower_network(reuse=False)
net2 = tower_network(reuse=True)

#similarity network
network = similarity_network( net1, net2)
#output layer
#network = tflearn.regression(network, optimizer='sgd', loss='hinge_loss', learning_rate=0.02)
network = tflearn.regression(network, optimizer='sgd', loss='categorical_crossentropy', learning_rate=0.02)

# Training
model = tflearn.DNN(network, tensorboard_verbose=0)
model.fit({'input': X}, {'target': Y}, n_epoch=20,
           validation_set=({'input': testX}, {'target': testY}),
snapshot_step=100, show_metric=True, run_id='convnet_mnist')
```

This still leads to an error about a missing variable 'input' which you define in the feed dict but nowhere else, but that's a different issue.

Comment: Setting net1 = tower_network (reuse = False ) leads to the same ERROR : Variable conv1/W already exists, disallowed. Did you mean to set reuse=True or reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE in VarScope? Originally defined at:

Comment: I edited my answer and added the modified source file.
This file solves the issue about the variable "conv1/W". There are some other issues left you need to resolve.

Also note that an error message saying "conv/W already exists" is different to an error message saying "conv/W does not exist".

Comment: Maybe I need to explain a bit further: You need to set reuse to False the first time you call tower_network. This first call will then create the variables. Succeeding calls to tower_network with reuse set to True will then use those variables and won't try to create any new ones.